# syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LISTS(name list)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have a project where I have to make "shoping list". It's my first time with SQlite DB.

I got:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "list": syntax error
**E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name list=
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "list": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LISTS(name list) VALUES (?)**
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                      at com.listof.myapplication.ListsManagerDAO.insertLists**(ListsManagerDAO.kt:37)**
                      at com.listof.myapplication.MainActivity$adding$1.onClick**(MainActivity.kt:50)**
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

and my code:

```
class ListsHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LISTS)
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
    //db!!.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+ TABLE_LISTS +"("+LIST_ID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ NAME_LIST +"TEXT);")
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_PRODUCT")
    db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_LISTS")
    onCreate(db)
}

companion object {

    // Tables Name
    val TABLE_PRODUCT = "PRODUCTS"
    val TABLE_LISTS = "LISTS"

    // Tables columns
    val LIST_ID= "_id"
    val NAME_LIST = "name_list"

    val _ID = LIST_ID
    val PRODUCT = "product"
    val AMOUNT = "amount"

    // Database Information
    internal val DB_NAME = "LISTS.DB"

    // database version
    internal val DB_VERSION = 1

    // Creating tables query
    /*private val CREATE_TABLE_LISTS = ("create table " + TABLE_LISTS + "("
            + LIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME_LIST + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            +_ID+ "INTEGER,"+" FOREIGN KEY("+_ID+ ") REFERENCES "+ TABLE_PRODUCT+"("+_ID+")")*/
    private val CREATE_TABLE_LISTS = ("create table " + TABLE_LISTS + "("
            + LIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + NAME_LIST + " TEXT NOT NULL"+");")
    private val CREATE_TABLE = ("create table " + TABLE_PRODUCT + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + PRODUCT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + AMOUNT + " TEXT)")

}
```

}

**ListManagerDAO code:**

```
class ListsManagerDAO(private val context: Context) {

private var dbHelper: ListsHelper? = null

private var database: SQLiteDatabase? = null

@Throws(SQLException::class)
fun open(): ListsManagerDAO {
    dbHelper = ListsHelper(context)
    database = dbHelper!!.writableDatabase

    return this
}


fun close() {
    dbHelper!!.close()
}


fun insertLists(lists:String){
    val listContentValue= ContentValues().apply {
        put(ListsHelper.NAME_LIST,lists)
    }
   database!!.insert(ListsHelper.TABLE_LISTS, null, listContentValue)
}

fun fetchLists(): Cursor? {
    val columns = arrayOf(ListsHelper.LIST_ID, ListsHelper.NAME_LIST)
    val cursor = database!!.query(ListsHelper.TABLE_LISTS, columns, null, null, null, null, null)
    cursor?.moveToFirst()
    return cursor
}


fun updateLists(_id: Long, lists: String){
    val listContentValue= ContentValues().apply {
        put(ListsHelper.NAME_LIST,lists)
    }
    database!!.update(ListsHelper.TABLE_LISTS, listContentValue, ListsHelper._ID + " = " + _id, null)
}


fun delete(_id: Long) {
    database!!.delete(ListsHelper.TABLE_LISTS, ListsHelper.LIST_ID + "=" + _id, null)
}
```

}

**MainActivity code:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
private var dbManager: ListsManagerDAO? = null
private var list: ListView? = null
private var adapter: SimpleCursorAdapter? = null
private var addtext: EditText? = null
internal var add: ImageView? = null

internal val from = arrayOf(ListsHelper.LIST_ID,ListsHelper.NAME_LIST)
internal val to = intArrayOf(R.id.list)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    dbManager = ListsManagerDAO(this)
    dbManager?.open()
    val cursor = dbManager?.fetchLists()

    list = findViewById(R.id.list) as ListView
    //list!!.emptyView = findViewById(R.id.editTextView)

    addtext = findViewById(R.id.editTextView) as EditText
    add = findViewById(R.id.imgViewAdd) as ImageView
  adapter=SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, cursor, from, to, 0)
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

    list!!.adapter = adapter
    adding()
}

fun adding() {
    add?.setOnClickListener(object : OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val listName: String = addtext!!.getText().toString()
            dbManager!!.insertLists(listName)
        }
    })


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    dbManager?.close()

}
```

}

I don't see any "missing quota" or soemthing like in:
[Android - SQLite - syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553760/android-sqlite-syntax-error-code-1-while-compiling-create-table)
or:
[table has no column named PosY (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Sample(Name,No,PosY,Img,PosX) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300807/table-has-no-column-named-posy-code-1-while-compiling-insert-into-samplen)

Comment: it is query error obviously, where is your insert into query in code?

Comment: Hi, in ListManagerDAO: 

fun insertLists(lists:String){
    val listContentValue= ContentValues().apply {
        put(ListsHelper.NAME_LIST,lists)
    }
   database!!.insert(ListsHelper.TABLE_LISTS, null, listContentValue)
}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the underscore between **name** and **list** i.e. it should be **name_list**.

However, I can't see why as `ListsHelper.NAME_LIST` is set using `val NAME_LIST = "name_list"` and that is what is used for the `ContentValues` in `insertLists`.

Comment: Hi,
I used: 
**val NAME_LIST = "name_list"**
as a companion object in ListsHelper class. Because of that I thought I can use it as ContentValues

Comment: I understand that. What I'm saying is the error is clear but how is not at all evident. All looks good according to the code.